How to predict python's random?
Based on the code provided below, how can I predict the seed or determine the generated numbers?
from random import randint, seed, sample

seed(randint(1, 2^256))
numbers = sample(range(1, 50), 6)

So far, I have tried setting the same local time, which generally works for reproducing results. However, I need a different method.

I do not understand what you mean. It's relatively really hard to do.

Unrelated but I don't think 2^256 does what you think it does.

Also, seeding a random number generator with a number drawn from that random number generator is pointless, and usually loses entropy.

What are you trying to accomplish? To ensure that numbers is a repeatable value, without altering the code fragment? Maybe write your own sitecustomize.py that monkey patches seed() and then set PYTHONPATH=path/to/that/module.

You don't want to tackle this via the seed. The PRNG's state is the important part for reproducibility, and the correct method to save/restore it is with getstate() and setstate().

If all you want to do is to get reproducible results, just initialize the seed at the beginning of your program to a specific number - any specific number.  Your program will then be deterministic.  This is a standard trick, often useful for debugging.  Once your program is working, just remove the line that sets the seed; the program then becomes non-deterministic.

I assume (and might be wrong) that this is a trick question.
This code seems designed to appear to produce a very large, unguessable seed:
seed(randint(1, 2^256))

What it really does is produce a random integer between 1 and 2 XOR 256, which is 258.
So, your seed is a number between 1 and 258.
Every seed will generate a very specific and deterministic sequence of random numbers. I haven't tried, but I am confident that each of those 258 seeds will generate sequences such that their first three numbers are all different.
Put another way, given the first three numbers, you can deduce which seed was used. At that point, knowing the seed and the position in the sequence, you can predict all subsequent numbers.


how can I predict the seed or determine the generated numbers?

By reading source code of everything involved and then running it line by line in virtualized environment to reproduce the results. Bottom line, by simulating it knowing the startup conditions.
randint is implemented here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c89adf385aaaca97c2ee9074f8b1fda0f57ad26/Lib/random.py#L336 based on randrange https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c89adf385aaaca97c2ee9074f8b1fda0f57ad26/Lib/random.py#L295 based on https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py#L275 _randbelow which is based on getrandbits https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/random.py#L893 which calls _random which is implemented in:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c89adf385aaaca97c2ee9074f8b1fda0f57ad26/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L440
   Used sources of entropy ordered by preference, preferred source first:

   - BCryptGenRandom() on Windows
   - getrandom() function (ex: Linux and Solaris): call py_getrandom()
   - getentropy() function (ex: OpenBSD): call py_getentropy()
   - /dev/urandom device

Now it get's very architecture, hardware specific. You have to track your operating system and it's implementation, and it might get more tricky with hardware random generators.
Now on linux getrandom is implemented here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12.4/source/drivers/char/random.c#L1388 which might call https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12.4/source/drivers/char/random.c#L442 which on the first look uses chacha20 random number generator algorithm which fills bytes  in crng_make_state https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12.4/source/drivers/char/random.c#L338 .
You have to write a linux kernel module that queries the current state of the chacha crng https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.12.4/source/drivers/char/random.c#L219 . Depending on the current state of the chacha, you could then write a program to predict in advance what output getrandom syscall will produce, then you can follow the chain of python code up until the randint code.

I have tried setting the same local time, which generally works for reproducing results

It's documented, from https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html :

random.seed(a=None, version=2)
Initialize the random number generator.
If a is omitted or None, the current system time is used. If randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used instead of the system time

System time is used only when no sources of randmness are in the operating system. This will be not the case on modern personal computers.
